# \left \right give inproper vertical spacing in fouriernc font

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, brackets, alignment

Here is a minimalist example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{E} [x \mid y ] $
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

But if I  use `\left` and `\right`, i.e., `\mathbb{E} \left[x \mid y \right]`, then the result would look like this:

[image]

The horizontal spacing looks fine. However, the brackets are also **vertically shifted down** a bit. Previously the bracket top is a bit higher than `E`, but now the top is aligned with the top of `E`.

Is it possible to just use the horizontal spacing without changing the vertical spacing with `\left` and `\right`?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making your example truly minimal. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico That looks very good ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character used is the same, because it fits the requirements for `\left` and `\right` size. The difference is that the brackets [] are not symmetric with respect to the math axis and `\left\right` instead places the obtained fences exactly so the character extends above the math axis as much as below.

In the picture below, `\mathaxis` produces a line that sits exactly over the math axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\newcommand{\mathaxis}{%
  \vrule width 1em
         height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt \relax
         depth \dimexpr-\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt \relax
}
\begin{document}

$\mathbb{E} [x \mid y ] \mathaxis$

$\mathbb{E} \left[x \mid y \right] \mathaxis$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another reason for not using `\left\right` unless really needed.

Comment: It is strange that the problem will not happen if we use the default computer modern font.

Comment: @NathanExplosion The parentheses in CM have the same height above the math axis as below.